# Two-Factor Authentication for Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange Open ID)

Tags: discussion

I'm a big fan of two factor authentication. I have not been able to find anyway to enable two factor authentication for my Stack Overflow account.

Are there any plans for SO to offer 2F? There are many discussions on SO about implementing 2F on OTHER services, so what is the deal with SO not providing 2F?

I searched high and low in the SO help documentation, but there is no mention of enabling 2F. Additionally, there seems to be no community discussion around SO offering 2F in the near future.

I would prefer there to be some sort of 2F for authentication, even if it is a simple SMS.

One would think there would be some sort of demand from the community for this, especially from all the users who have built impressive professional reputations on the community over the years.

Comment: Should have asked this on meta. Don't you think so?

Comment: Couldn't till just now. Had to get the ball rolling somehow.

Comment: Correction, I am ONE point shy of being able to participate in Meta discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mathews for pointing me in the right direction. It seems the only way to have any two factor authentication is to not use Stack Exchange OpenID. The feature was explored and abandoned.