# Support for using Yubikey to log in

Tags: feature-request

I'd really like to be able to associate my Yubikey with my account, and use it to log in without having to enter username or password.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318402/215552

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10254/why-does-the-yubico-openid-not-work-with-stackoverflow they support OpenID, so you should be able to log in with it.

Comment: @Stijn I used to use OpenID, but it's not the same as Yubikey integration.

Comment: @Stijn Having to go to an external site is an unnecessary extra step. But I'll give this a try, thanks for the pointer. :)